# MS Access 2013 event trigger in module, not class module

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a number of forms that have the same controls, Year for example, that are used for different reports. There are dozens of forms with the control named Year with GotFocus / OnFocus event triggers. I am trying to avoid writing a bunch of class modules with pretty much the same code which would require something like:

```
Private Sub Year_OnFocus()
```

I would like to write a function in a module so I can refer to Year relative to the form it is one with:

```
Forms!Home!NavigationSubForm.Form.Year.OnGotFocus
```

This does not seem to work, let alone behave the same way as the `Private Sub Year_GotFocus`. So was wondering if anyone has any constructive suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `WithEvents`. Documentation is poor, but a nice intro is here. Browse to the header *A Little History*:

[A Little History](http://jwcolby.blogspot.dk/)

Comment: Or better, just search for "With Events" in that document. This will lead to directly to the code sample. Note that you will still need a few lines per "Year"-Control to hook it up with the common event handler class. IF all these controls are in Subforms you can maybe get away with putting the setup code in the Main form.