# Access 2016 set control events at runtime

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Is there a way to add an event handler for a control at runtime?

Regard this code (in the form I have only TextBox1):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents tb As Access.TextBox

Private Sub Form_Load()
  set tb = TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub tb_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Debug.Print "tb_MouseDown"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
  Debug.Print "TextBox1_MouseDown"
End Sub
```

With that code, the two handlers are called.
If I remove the handler TextBox1_MouseDown, the tb_MouseDown is not fired.

Comment: This is not how to use WithEvents. You need a class module to handle that. Read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448624/ms-access-2013-event-trigger-in-module-not-class-module/35453202#35453202)

Comment: What is there of strange in that use? I have used this in VB6 for years in the past. When and object is declared WithEvents, at instantiation time, the runtime calls IUnknonw->QueryInterface to search for a IConnectionPointContainer support, then search for IConnectionPoint.. In VB6 the runtime generates a sink object that implements the source interface on-the-fly which, in turn, forwards call to any events handler in the code (both in Classes or in Forms). Here seems this not happens.

Comment: Can't tell. Have never used VB6. This may be a difference between VB6 and VBA.